# php headers_sent function is not working

Tags: php, http-headers, header, echo

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<?php
echo 'teste'; // output here
echo headers_sent(); // no output here!
?>
```

Why headers_sent() doesn't output in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your php.ini config file and look for line containing `output_buffering` and make sure it looks like:

`output_buffering = Off`

If you have it Off then `echo headers_sent()` should output `1`

If you have it On then `echo headers_sent()` won't output anything because headers_sent() in that case will return FALSE, because headers (meaning not HTML `<h1>` but HTTP response headers) were not sent yet because output is buffered.

To force sending headers and output echo-ed so far you may call `flush()`

Comment: You was right. What are the consequences with this directive off?

Comment: If it's Off and you didn't called ob_start() then first echo (or print or any other command that causes output) will start outputting response to clients browser, making you unable to use functions that change http headers like header() or setcookie() - calling those functions will result in error "headers already sent"

Comment: You was right. I've set it to Off and it's working! What are the consequences with this directive off?

Comment: The directive is generally off, so it is good practice to code for it being off. All it does is saves the output in a buffer and waits for the script to finish to display everything at once. If the script is coded right, there should be no need to worry about the output_buffering being on or off as it should work for both.

Answer (score 2):

Because it returns true or false.

```
var_dump(headers_sent());
```

Should display (one or the other below)

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

It is working, it just will not output text, *if it is false*, <del>as it is not text</del> it is a `boolean` value. The general use of this function is meant for an if statement, not a displaying statement, if you want to display it simply use the `ternary operator`

```
echo (headers_sent())?'true':'false';
```

**Edit**

Thanks to Victor for correcting me: It will return 1 if true, an empty string if false.

**Update**

Why does [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/headers_sent) return false? Well to clarify I will post from the manual:

> headers_sent — Checks if or where
>   headers have been sent

Basically, when you have any output, that sends the headers automatically to the browser and starts the body. For example:

```
<?php
echo "test";
echo headers_sent(); // should yield 1
?>
```

That should display 1, since we had an echo statement for the `headers_sent` call.

```
<?php
echo headers_sent(); // should yield empty string
?>
```

That will display an empty string, given that no output is before the headers_sent() call. The above *assumes* that output_buffering is turned off. As with `output_buffering` being on it saves all output till the script is done processing then displays that output, thus the header / body tag get sent at the end of the script.

Hopefully that clears it up. If not, see the manual link I posted above and read through the examples at the manual.

Comment: Converting `true` to a string should yield `1` ... absence of output indicates that the function returned `false` (which yields an empty string).

Comment: true value is printed in this way: '1'

Comment: var_dump(headers_sent()); == 'bool(false)'

Comment: Right, as Victor Nicollet stated, false yields an empty string, so if the value is false nothing will be displayed on the screen. If you want output, see the echo method I posted above to show `true` or `false` in string form.

Comment: Ok, false is not showed. I want to know why this code returns false. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if `ob_start` has been called before the code you showed has been executed.